# Can a photosensitive drum be damaged if cleaned with isopropyl alcohol?

Tags: printer, cleaning

Some background:
I've got a drum for a Brother MFC-8710dw that has some streaks.  As per the instructions I've been cleaning it with a dry lint free cloth.

I've noticed though that lots of people online recommend that you clean them with isopropyl alcohol, yet the instructions from Brother specifically forbid the use of alcohol (and for that matter any liquids in general).

Are the people at Brother being overly cautious?  Or can the use of isopropyl alcohol on the photosensitive drum really cause damage?  And if so what sort of damage can it cause?

Comment: My suggestion (not an answer) would be that if you're about to discard / replace the drum, consider trying the alcohol to see if it works. If it doesn't then you're back to where you started. No loss.

Comment: I went ahead and used it and it appeared to work well without damaging the drum.  I've repeated this now several times with great success.

Answer (score 1):

It mentions using a cotton swab after printing a `Drum Dot Print` to get specks and streaks off the drum. Can apply a bit more pressure and be more accurate with a cotton swab than with a cloth. (From the online instructions for [Title: Clean the drum unit](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/BSC/public/us/us_ot/en/faq/faq/000000/002200/000056/faq002256_014.html?reg=us&c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=mfc8710dw_us&Cat=7)) There is a specific warning against using liquids on the drum surface which should probably be followed.

[image]

Comment: The drum has an organic photosensitive coating that could be damaged by contact with solvents.

Comment: So alcohol could wear away at the coating?

Answer (score 1):

My wife wrapped two 8.5" x 4" adhesive labels onto an area 1/8th the size of the fuser drum in her Brother 8890-DRW; it was located on the left-hand side and rolled almost 1/2 of the way around the drum in a folded, jammed, corner shaped glob of destruction.

After convincing her that my many years of IT experience had prepared me for this problem, not unlike the myriad other showstopping IT fubar's I've unfubarred, and that she should dial back her automatic  OCD picking mechanisms and allow me to remedy the situation rather than to proceed to use her fingers in an additionally fubar'ing attempt to unstick them while contaminating the drum with human salts, oils etc. (certainly not that it would be a bad way to go by the way, if you can imagine Mrs Universe de-label jamming a hosed up LASER PRN TONER DRUM; never boring, seriously).

So I took it to my Mad Lab (I don't do caves), separated the toner cart and proceeded to heat the label remnants with my rework station's hot air tool set at 190F for almost 30 seconds (via the left hand) and with the right I used a pair of plastic tweezers to easily remove most of the label remnants  from the DRUM. This took all of 2 minutes because 190F seems to be a really good temp to heat label adhesive and the toner drum is designed for relatively high temps so the labels came right off after about 20-30 secs of heating (try to avoid extended heating though, if beyond 45 secs then back off for 30 secs before resuming).  It can be difficult to grab the bunched, folded labels with plastic tweezers but I don't recommend using anything made of metal on anything made of "FUSER" (DRUM, ROLLER, etc.) because of the soft plasticity. Now you won't be able to get all of the labels off of the DRUM because, well, its heated label adhesive so you can gently push / 'scrape' the drum with any suitable plastic tool that isn't pointy, or sharp (even a plastic paint scraper will work, JUST BE GENTLE and don't wear out your welcome, etc). You can't be going into FLEA BITTEN MANIAC MODE to scrape off these labels, though. The heating tool should be doing the work and you should use almost no pressure to remove the labels (grasp them whenever possible). After you have removed as much as you can with the heating and tweezing (3 or 4 mins, don't over heat by lingering or using more than 200F) you can then proceed with the GRANDE FINALE or 'coupe de gras'. For this I use 90% isopropyl alcohol (lower % than 85-90 has too much water and will only smear, ultimately requiring a trip to the ISOPROPYL ALCOHOL STORE for 85% or above (you could probably also use ethyl alc (90-100 proof or higher).  You really don't need any special, luxurious, lint free cotton or silk, etc.  You can use the cheapest paper towel that Walmart carries, torn in half and then folded twice each way. Pour some alcohol onto the paper towel getting it fairly saturated but NOT dripping and proceed to clean up any lingering clumps of label and adhesive film that will remain on the DRUM.  No need and not recommended to dry the DRUM afterwards.  You can see the liquid evaporating and if you need to go over any spots again with the wet paper towel.  Don't be greedy/stingy with them because you will start redistributing the adhesive, so replace the towel with a fresh one for heavy contamination.  Its no super skill, you will quickly be really good at doing this and if you've never cleaned your DRUM before then you will probably notice improved printing (less spots, more white paper, cleaner, clearer, etc.)  After you have the DRUM spotless put it all back together and print the night (or day) away.

Alcohol is an amazing all purpose IT cleaner and I honestly think Brother wants you to buy some sort of special brand (Brother brand) of DRUM CLEANER (most likely 80% isopropyl).  These companies can be so misleading and manipulative.  90% isopropyl is the best printer drum cleaner I've ever seen; I've been cleaning LASER and INKJET PRNs with it for decades, so clean away and worry not! (Even if alcohol were somehow damaging to your printer, what good is a printer that is constantly jamming or printing illegibly anyhow?  i mean in that situation your printer is essentially instantaneously useless, whereas some overly cautious users would have you believe that substances which can clean are going to somehow dissolve your printer, etc.  (Really, its not common ordinary H2SO4 after all...).

Required materials:

- Plastic tweezers or similar (not pointy)
- Heating tool (rework station, paint gun, blow dryer??) (No more than 200F)
- 2 or 3 paper towels (selecta size LOL)
- 4 to 6 ounces of 85-92% Isopropyl Alcohol
- 1 gummed up, jammed up, filthed up LASER PRN FUSER/TONER DRUM

Answer (score 1):

Directly from Brother's website, contrary to what a person answered above, you most certainly CAN use isopropyl alcohol.  Be sure to keep your hands away from the drum, as in the oils and such. Treat the drum like a Halogen bulb, use gloves. Brother recommends 91% isopropyl alcohol to be used, but a less concentrated is fine.

[image: Screenshot from Brother's website]

Comment: Thanks for this!  I tried using isopropyl on a Samsung laser printer drum and it worked a treat!  There were white splotches appearing on the page where the toner was missing.  I wiped the whole drum despite not being able to see any marks on it, and it solved the problem - nice clean prints again.  I tried wiping the drum with a dry microfibre cloth first but that didn't make any difference - it needed the isopropyl to properly clean it.